Ashura and the exodus
Asalam alaykom brothers
I hope you are all doing good.
This is my first post here so I hope some one can help me with this.
As we know the prophet peace be upon him ordered us to fast ashurah according to the hadith based on the fact that Musa AS was saved along with bani Israel on this day.
But Jews have been celebrating this event for the last 3000 years on passover holiday which starts on the 14th day of the first month in their calender.
Now I know that the hebrew calender differs from our calender, but still the passover always starts on full moon so according to their tradition in cant be on the 10th.
Also, thet dont fast at all at passover.
On the other hand they have a holiday on the 10th of their first month which is a very important holiday called yim kibbor I think where they fast, but it has nothing to do with the exodus.
Another problem is, if the 2 calenders are different (which they are), how come the 10th muharamm of that year that the prophet ordered it was the same as the 10 muharram from the time of the exodus and both coincide with jewish calender?
How can we explain this?
Jazakum Allahu Khairan.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that your question is fairly addressed in Why the jewish pesach or passover and the Islamic ashura don't fall on the same day?, if you agree then mark this question as a duplicate of yours.

The Ashura (10th) of Muharram is the day Imam Hussain PBUH was martyred by Yazid's army, and is a day of pain in hearth and wail. In Shia Ahadeeth it is stated that when the army of Yazid martyred Imam and several children of the holy prophet PBUH and Imam's most pious companions, Umayyad celebrated the day as a great victory of Umayyad over Bani Hashem (something like the tribe of the holy prophet PBUHH, a sub-tribe of Quraysh), fasting the day for it to appear a holy day, to praise Allah for granting them such a victory. According to Hadeeth, this is the very reason why it is discouraged for any Shia Muslim to fast this day, avoiding resembling to the enemies of Allah AWJ and the holy prophet PBUHH; and any Hadeeth that encourages it is thus assumed to be fabricated by Umayyads. The Hadeeth you point to should not be different at least in Shia view.
